# Using interception to implement caching - how to define keys?

Tags: caching, unity-container

**TL;DR** *Can someone point me to a through implementation of a caching system that is added to the solution through interception?*

I'm refactoring one of my solutions so that cross-cutting concerns are implemented through Unity Intercept. I've read the guides from MSFT, and now I think I can very easily implement the interception behaviors.

**However**, I was wondering about caching; I want to consistently use the cache regions and keys throughout the solution. Furthermore, I have key-specif configurations for expiration on my caching system.

On one example in the Unity's Developer Guide, it checks the method name -- this is a bad approach since it would mean altering the implementation everytime a new class/method must use cache (obviously).

I'm having this (mad) idea of implementing a configurable Interceptor that learns how to compose the region and key from the given parameters, and is configurable for each class(type)/method. However this would push a lot of responsibility to configuration; I don't like the feeling that I'm programming in the *.config file.

As you can see, I'm a tad bit lost on how to go about this. I don't like singletons and right now the caching system is a singleton, accessed everywhere by the solution. Can someone link me to a good documentation on how I should proceed about this? Is it possible to add cache and have proper keys/regions defined on the cache?

Answer (score 0):

Quick search on the similar matter lead me to the ["Attribute Based Cache using Unity Interception"](https://unitycacheaop.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex. Entire project looks to be abandoned in some Alpha stage, however, it should provide you with the baseline to start with.